# How many days does an iOS app stay in the iPad if I publish it from XCode to my iPad?

Tags: ios

Recently, I have developed an iOS app which I built it into my iPad device. After a few weeks, the app can no longer be opened. How many days does an app stay in the iPad during this testing phase? Or does it switch off after days of inactivity?

Answer (score 0):

If I deploy the application using the Run command in Xcode, and then remove the USB cable, generally this terminates the application on the device within a few seconds.
With free account after 7 days, with paid account after 1 year

Answer (score 0):

If you have a free/unpaid developer account, your provisioning profiles expire after 7 days.

With a paid account, those profiles expire after 1 year.